# the code seems to skip this code for my collider, how do I make it work?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, collider

I have visited many forums for this problem and I have searched lots of tutorials for this issue.
Here's my code :

```
private void OnTriggerEnter(Collider collision)
{
    GameObject collisionGameObject = collision.gameObject;

    if (collisionGameObject.name == "playerBullet")
    {
        Debug.Log("damage taken");
        TakeDamage(40);
    }
}
```

I should be doing everything right, what went wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure of the following things:

1. Your GameObject with the script must have a collider.
2. Your GameObject with the script must be set to Collider and not Trigger
3. Your GameObject with the script must have a RigidBody
4. Your Bullet must have a collider.
5. Your Bullet must have a collider that is not a trigger.

Comment: I found out my enemy does not have a rigidbody, but, when I add a rigidbody my enemy becomes very shaky.

Comment: @bobmaximus You can set your rigidBody on your Enemy as Kenematic = true.

Comment: also, for some reason it does not detect collisions. Is there a certain setting in the rigidbody that I have to configure or is it something else? the shaky enemy glitch has been fixed.

Comment: Instead of using `OnTriggerEnter(Collider collider)` use `OnCollisionEnter(Collision collision)`

Comment: it did not work, sadly